# How to Delete Quote item Based on the condition in magento 2

Tags: magento2, quote, delete, quoteitem

I have requirement like below.

I need to read all quote items and their sku, against the custom table,

If value matched, need to delete that quote item and update qty 1 for remaining items but this code is not working for me,

```
Class DeleteItem extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{{
 protected $checkoutSession;    
 protected $cart;
 protected $_resource;
 public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
 \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
 { 
   $this->cart = $cart;
   $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
  $this->_resource = $resource;
   parent::__construct($context);
 }

public function execute() {
   $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
            $quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach($quoteItems as $item) {                    
                $productSku = $item->getProduct()->getSku();                    
                $tableSKu  = $this->checkIfExist($productSku);
                if($tableSKu){
                    $item->delete();
                    continue;
                }                       

                $item->setQty(1);
                $item->save();
            }
        $message = "You alredy bought this Product";
            $this->messageManager->addError(__($message));
            $cartUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($cartUrl)->sendResponse();            
            exit;
       }
public function checkIfExist($productSku){
   $connection = $this->getConnection();
   $sql = "select * from custom_table where sku='".$productSku."'";
   $resultProduct = $connection->query($sql);
   $resultQuery = $resultProduct->fetchAll();

  if(!empty($resultQuery)){ 
    $parent_sku = $resultQuery[0]['parent_sku'];
    return true;
   }
  }else{
   return false;
    }
    }
 public function getConnection(){
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    return $connection;
  }

 }
```

Right now the item is deleting but if navigated to cart page, the summary being shown right hand side, where item in cart is empty

Can anyone look into this and update me the solution,

Thanks

Comment: this doesn't solve your problem, but you should never write SQL queries

Comment: @PhilippSander, okay, right now item is deleting but cart summary is still there

Comment: @PhilippSander, Can you provide me any solution for it please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code:

```
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
Class DeleteItem extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{{
     protected $checkoutSession;    
     protected $cart;
     protected $_resource;
     protected $quoteItem;
       protected $resultRedirect;
       protected $messageManager;
     public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
      \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
      \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
     \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
      \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem,
      \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
      ResultFactory $resultRedirect
     { 
       $this->cart = $cart;
       $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
       $this->_resource = $resource;
       $this->quoteItem=$quoteItem;
       $this->resultRedirect=$resultRedirect;
       $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
       parent::__construct($context);
     }

    public function execute() {
       $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
                $quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
                foreach($quoteItems as $item) {                    
                    $productSku = $item->getProduct()->getSku();                    
                    $tableSKu  = $this->checkIfExist($productSku);
                    $itemid=$item->getItemId();
                    if($tableSKu){
                         $quoteItem=$this->quoteItem->load($itemid);
                         $quoteItem->delete();//deletes the item

                        continue;
                    }                       

                    $item->setQty(1);
                    $item->save();
                }
               $this->messageManager->addError( __('Item deleted Successfully !') );
               $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
               $resultRedirect->setPath("checkout");
               return $resultRedirect;

           }
    public function checkIfExist($productSku){
       $connection = $this->getConnection();
       $sql = "select * from custom_table where sku='".$productSku."'";
       $resultProduct = $connection->query($sql);
       $resultQuery = $resultProduct->fetchAll();

      if(!empty($resultQuery)){ 
        $parent_sku = $resultQuery[0]['parent_sku'];
        return true;
       }
      }else{
       return false;
        }
        }
     public function getConnection(){
        $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
        return $connection;
      }

     }
```

I have just modified your code to use **quoteItem** Model because it seems that your code is deleting item from collection but not from checkoutSession.

Comment: Yes, this one didn't work for me @Khushbu

Comment: hi @khushbu,  I need to show error message with redirect to checkout, but its not showing for me. canu help me pls

Comment: When you want to show error message?

Comment: After deleting item..

Comment: I have updated code. Try that

Comment: I used this code in observer, can i use above code for redirect?

Comment: can i post my observer code as new question?

Comment: yes code will be slightly different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96088/discussion-between-manjunath-and-khushbu).

Comment: pls check the chat @Khushbu

Answer (score 1):

If using **quoteItem** doesn't work then you should try to update cart data as below:

Create **sections.xml** file in

> Vendor/Package/etc/frontend

Write below code in that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="routeid/folder/DeleteItem"> <!-- Your action path -->
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```